# How to search for an item in a vector struct?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to create a function that will find an item in my struct which uses vectors but I keep getting the error:

no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'video_games' and 'const std::basic_string')

```
void DataStoreVectors::findItem(vector<video_games> &Video_Games) {

    video_games videoGames;
    
    cout << "Type a Video Game to Find: ";
    cin >> videoGames.game_name;

    vector<video_games>::iterator it;
    it = find(Video_Games.begin(), Video_Games.end(), videoGames.game_name);
    if(it != Video_Games.end())
        cout << "Found: " << videoGames.game_name << endl;
    else
        cout << "Not Found." << endl;

}
```

What am I doing wrong and what does this error mean?

Comment: The compiler doesn't know how to compare a video_game and a std::string.  You need to implement operator== to compare them, or provide a comparison function in the std::find call.

Answer (score 0):

Replace *videoGames.game_name* in the parameters of ***find***  with *videoGames*. It will compile. It will work if your structure video_games has operator == which returns true if game_name properties are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment:

`std::find` needs to know when it has found a match. If you give is some object, it will try to compare that object against each item in the collection, using `==`.

A video game is not a string, comparing them make no sense. Therefore overloading operator== as was suggested in some comments is not a good design.

Consider this alternative:

```
auto it = std::find(
    Video_Games.begin(), Video_Games.end(),
    [&](const auto & game) { return game.game_name == videoGames.game_name; }
);
if(it != Video_Games.end())
    std::cout << "Found: " <<it->game_name <<std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "Not Found." <<std::endl;
```

We tell `std::find` what it should consider a match for this specific search, by giving it a function that returns `true` when it's found, instead of letting it use `==`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have a few questions. 1. Does 'const auto' create another object so that one object isn't being compared to itself as I had done before? 2. What exactly is the overloading operator==? Is it what you used in the return? If so I'm confused on what you mean.

Comment: Please open other questions if you have other questions :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store the name of the video game in a `video_games` object, you can just store it in a string `video_game_name`.

Then, from c++20, you could implement it like this:

```
auto it = std::ranges::find(Video_Games, video_game_name, 
                            &video_games::game_name);
```